# Gradle failing to build at startScripts task: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.getMain()'

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I'm trying to build a JavaFX application using Gradle. This is my first time using Gradle, so it is a fresh install. Like the title suggests, when I go to build my application, there is a build failure when it gets to the task responsible for creating the start scripts: startScripts.
The traceback goes as such:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.getMain()'  
at org.javamodularity.moduleplugin.tasks.AbstractExecutionMutator.getMainClassName(AbstractExecutionMutator.java:26)    
at org.javamodularity.moduleplugin.tasks.StartScriptsMutator.buildStartScriptsJvmArgs(StartScriptsMutator.java:83)  
at org.javamodularity.moduleplugin.tasks.StartScriptsMutator.configureStartScriptsDoFirst(StartScriptsMutator.java:61)  
at org.javamodularity.moduleplugin.tasks.StartScriptsMutator$1.execute(StartScriptsMutator.java:42) 
at org.javamodularity.moduleplugin.tasks.StartScriptsMutator$1.execute(StartScriptsMutator.java:39) 
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:828)    
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:801)    
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:242)  
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)    
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)    
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)    
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)    
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157) 
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)  
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)  
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)  
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:227)  
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:210) 
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:193) 
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:166)    
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:105)    
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:44)  
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:59)  
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:56)  
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)    
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)    
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)    
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)    
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157) 
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)  
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53) 
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:56) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:44) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:67) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:37) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)   
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:28) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.executeDelegateBroadcastingChanges(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:100)   
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:72)   
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:50)   
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:40) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:29) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:166)  
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:70)  
at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)   
at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)    
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:68)   
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:46)   
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:91)    
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)  
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)   
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:37)   
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:65)   
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:36)   
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)    
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)    
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:76) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:37) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:94)   
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:49)   
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:71) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:45) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:177) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:81) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:53) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)  
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36)   
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)   
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:75) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:41) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:32)    
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:287)    
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:21) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27) 
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:47)   
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:34)   
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:64)  
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:146)   
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)  
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)   
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)   
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57) 
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)   
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)   
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)   
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)  
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)  
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)    
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)    
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)    
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)    
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157) 
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)  
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53) 
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73) 
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52) 
at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)   
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:337)   
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:324)   
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:317)  
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)  
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)   
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)   
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)   
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
```

It should also be mentioned that Gradle is warning me about a deprecation:

```
The AbstractCompile.destinationDir property has been deprecated.    
This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 9.0.  
Please use the destinationDirectory property instead.
```

My build.gradle file is as follows:

```
plugins {
  id 'application'
  id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.10'
  id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.24.4'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
    version = "20"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'tech.jimothy.InitiativeTracker'
    }
}

application {
    mainClass = "tech.jimothy.InitiativeTracker"
    mainModule = "tech.jimothy"
}

jlink {
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'tech.jimothy'
    }
}
```

'gradle -version' yields:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.1.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-04-21 12:31:26 UTC
Revision:     1cf537a851c635c364a4214885f8b9798051175b

Kotlin:       1.8.10
Groovy:       3.0.15
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          20.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 20.0.1+9)
OS:           Linux 6.3.5-arch1-1 amd64
```

At first, I thought maybe the deprecation had something to do with it, but the documentation on it wasn't too clear to me. I am new to the Gradle DSL based on Groovy, so a lot of this is confusing to me. I would really appreciate some guidance with this error.

Comment: Seems like a plugin applied implicitly with the `org.openjfx.javafxplugin` plugin isn't compatible with your version of Gradle. Try updating that plugin from `0.0.10` to the latest version (`0.0.14` at the time of writing this comment).